# How to change bootstrap3 nav-pills active color in affix/scrollspy via CSS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried several ways to override bootstrap3 nav-pills active color via CSS but it seems the LESS takes priority. I tried also using !important on the relative CSS properties with no luck: the LESS always has priority.

The only way I found is to obviously recompile bootstrap with customized nav-pills colors, but I'd prefer to use CSS so I can rely on CDN.

Any hint?

The relative affix/scrollspy is working of course via:

```
<body  data-spy="scroll">
...
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked affix-top hidden-print" data-toggle="affix" data-spy="affix">
```

Relative [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uyD9/)

Answer (score 7):

Not sure what you did, but this code works:

```
.nav-pills > li.active > a {
    background-color:red;
}
// This changes the color of the active

.nav-pills>li.active>a:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
// This changes the color of the hovered pill
```